# jQuery UI draggable with CSS clipping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have the following (greatly simplified) HTML, generated by a script I have no control over:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4em; height: 0px;">
    <span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1em 1000em 2em -0.5em); top: -2em; left: 0;">
        <span>
            <span class="to-be-dragged" style="position: relative;">
                content
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to make `.to-be-dragged` draggable with jQuery UI. The code for doing that would be something like this:

```
$(".to-be-dragged").draggable()
```

Unfortunately, one of the parent spans of my draggable span has the `clip` property. This causes the dragged `span` to disappear upon leaving the clipped area (because `overflow` is hidden as a requirement of `clip`). I attempted to just remove `clip` on the parent `span`, but that caused the clipped parent `span` to grow in size and cover up existing content which I needed to remain clickable. So the `clip` property either has to remain or be replaced with something that has the same effect.

I'm unsure how to reconcile `clip` and jQuery UI draggable such that the clipped `span` remains clipped/small, but the draggable `span` can be dragged out of its parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!

I added `helper: "clone"` and `appendTo: "#parent-div"` to the draggable properties, and then hid the original element in the `start` method of the draggable, reshowing it in the `stop` method. `#parent-div` is the division which the top-level `span` is contained within. So the code looks like this in CoffeeScript:

```
target.draggable
    start: (event, ui) ->
        # Hide the original variable we are dragging.
        $(event.target).fadeTo(0, 0)

    stop: (event, ui) ->
        # Show the original variable we are dragging.
        $(event.target).fadeTo(0, 1)

    containment: "#parent-div"

    revert: true
    helper: "clone"
    appendTo: "#parent-div"
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
target.draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        return $(event.target).fadeTo(0, 0);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        return $(event.target).fadeTo(0, 1);
    },
    containment: "#parent-div",
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "#parent-div"
});
```